# getting a path in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

my combobox is populated with

6.70_Extensions

7.00_Extensions

7.10.000_Tip

7.10_Extensions

if my combobox selected value is `6.70_Extensions` and during a button event, how do i select a path from an xml file (antcheckin.xml) with `"6.70_Extensions"`? for example: selecting `"C:\Work\6.70_Extensions\folder"` from an xml file.

note: The combobox selected value is

`var buildStream =((DataRowView)BuildstreamComboBox.SelectedItem).Row["value"].ToString()`

Basically after selecting this path, i am going to make this folder non-readonly.

So this is what i have done previously(note: this combo box was intially not populated with xml data and i managed to populate it with xml data and hence i need a new code for this below as i cannot depend on selected index now).

```
// the following is used to ensure the folder checked out is now not "read only"


if (BuildstreamComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Work\\6.70_Extensions\\folder");
            foreach (var file in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        }
        if (BuildstreamComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Work\\7.00_Extensions\\folder");
            foreach (var file in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        }
        if (BuildstreamComboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Work\\7.10.000_Tip\\folder");
            foreach (var file in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        }
```

antcheckin.xml:

```
<project>
    <buildmachine4>
            <checkout1 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/6.70_Extensions/folder/"'/>
            <checkout2 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/7.00_Extensions/folder/"'/> 
        </buildmachine4>
        <buildmachine5>

        <checkout3 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/7.10.000_Tip/folder/"'/>
    </buildmachine5>

</project>
```

**EDIT 1:** Hi guys, i will be doing a search into my antcheckin.xml file but i am kind of stuck to get parse the attribute out:

```
public void BuildButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // the following is used to ensure the folder checked out is now not "read only"

    // load your XML
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Work\ANTCheckIN.xml");


    XElement mainItem = doc.Descendants("project")
                  .Where(mi => mi.Attribute("folder").Value.Contains(buildStream)

    ....
    //what should be added here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of LINQ TO XML and do search attribute valut in you xml

something as below

```
from el in root.Elements("rootlement")
where
(from add in el.Descendants()
where
add.Attribute("MyAttribute") != null
&&
add.Attribute("MyAttribute").Value.Contains("ZXCV")
select add)
.Any()
select el;
```

Comment: but how do i just get the `"C:/Work/6.70_Extensions/folder"`? because there is `-f` and `-R` in front of it

Comment: @jeremychan - replace -f and -r by string manipulation function after extacting vlue of attribute

Comment: @jeremychan Are you able to edit the XML file? Are the flags necessary? If they are, I would suggest that you have separate out the `-f` and `-R` flags from the folder attribute. For example something like this (I have assumed the meaning of the flags): `<checkout1 exe="wco" folder="C:/Work/6.70_Extensions/folder/" recursive="true" files="true"/>`.

Comment: hi -f and -r refers to something else